# How to rewrite imports for compiled sass?

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I have a problem, I'm trying to build a component library and at the same time I would like to have a dev server in the same project for fast debugging and developing of this component library.

Currently my configuration is next, for library building I use typescript to transpile to es5 and I have all styles as scss and compile them into css with node-sass. For this config to work I import styles as css(not sass) since otherwise scss files won't be found in lib directory.

Here are my source files:

[image: source files]

[image]

And this is lib folder after being compiled:

[image]

And this is my configuration for building lib folder
[image]

Now I'm trying to configure dev server with webpack and I decided to import components directly from src (not lib) to fast forward development. And it doesn't work with my current styles imports (as css) because webpack compiles my scss styles as a big bundle and merges it into js bundle but those statements where I import css are still there which case errors.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Title.css'
```

I believe there is a solution to this problem but which way to take I'm not sure, please suggest!

My preference is to keep library building without webpack and use webpack for dev server